# Can the angular-ui-bootstrap typeahead be used as an auto-complete?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm looking to add an 'auto-complete' feature to text fields and textareas in my Angular app. I'm looking for something similar to GitHub's @-mentions, i.e. when the user types a specific key (e.g. `@`) a dropdown box appears so that the user can select the text to insert. Something like this:

[image: Github autocomplete example]

I'm already using angular-ui bootstrap and it looks like [the typeahead directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) almost does what I need, however the typeahead is revealed after any character is pressed. I only want it to be revealed when the specific key is pressed, e.g. `@`.

Is there any way to get this typeahead to do what I want, or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As promised on GitHub, I would take a look at your question.

To answer your question: no. With a far-fetched yes. You could probably go all the way and invest quite some time to make UI Bootstrap's typeahead work for your implementation but there are better solutions out there that are meant to do that single purpose.

Googling "angularjs mention autocomplete" resulted in some usable libraries:

https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io

https://github.com/alihaghighatkhah/angular-otobox

These could be helpful for you.